# How do I connect my Frontend, Backend, and DB services to view app on an EKS cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, mariadb, amazon-eks

I have a Java, react, and mysql application and a CI/CD pipeline on GitLab that builds, tests, and deploys my app to an EKS cluster. I am running into an issue where I am able to view my front once it is deployed, but there are some communication issues between the services preventing the data showing on the app. Please find below some info about my service and deployment configurations and errors I am receiving.

Deployment.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: react-frontend
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: react
 replicas: 2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: react
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: react
       image: user/my-frontend:2024-02-28_16-39-01
       ports:
       - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: java-backend
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: java
 replicas: 2
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: java
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: java
       image: user/my-backend:2024-02-28_16-28-13
       ports:
       - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: mariadb-database
spec:
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: mariadb
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: mariadb
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: mariadb
       image: mariadb:10.6.4-focal
       ports:
       - containerPort: 3306
       volumeMounts:
       - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
         name: mariadb-storage
     volumes:
     - name: mariadb-storage
       persistentVolumeClaim:
         claimName: mariadb-pvc
```

Service.yaml:

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: react-service
spec:
 type: LoadBalancer
 ports:
 - port: 80
 selector:
   app: react
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: java-service
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 8080
 selector:
   app: java
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: mariadb-service
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 ports:
 - port: 3306
 selector:
   app: mariadbv
```

.gitlab-ci.yaml

```
stages:
  - build_and_push
  - test
  - deploy
 
variables: 
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/ 
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2 
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" 

build_and_push_backend: 
  stage: build_and_push 
  image: docker:latest 
  services: 
    - docker:dind 
  before_script: 
    - docker login -u user -p 123 
  script: 
    - VERSION=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
    - docker build -t user/my-backend:$VERSION ./backend 
    - docker push user/my-backend:$VERSION 

build_and_push_frontend: 
  image: docker:latest 
  stage: build_and_push 
  services: 
    - docker:dind 
  before_script: 
    - docker login -u user -p 123 
  script: 
    - VERSION=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
    - docker build -t user/my-frontend:$VERSION ./frontend 
    - docker push user/my-frontend:$VERSION

test_frontend:
  stage: test
  image: node:latest
  script:
  - cd frontend
  - npm install
  - npm run
  - npm test

test_backend:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.8.4-openjdk-11
  script:
    - cd backend
    - mvn test

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image:
    name: bitnami/kubectl:latest
    entrypoint: ['']
  script:
    - kubectl config get-contexts
    - kubectl config use-context irs_ira/devops-demos:eks-agent # Set by GitLab Kubernetes Agent, if necessary
    - kubectl get nodes
    - kubectl delete namespace eks-sample-app
    - kubectl create namespace eks-sample-app
    - kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml -n eks-sample-app
    - kubectl apply -f service.yaml -n eks-sample-app
    - kubectl get all -n eks-sample-app
    - kubectl get svc -n eks-sample-app
   # - kubectl delete namespace eks-sample-app
    - kubectl get pods --namespace eks-sample-app
    #- kubectl delete service java-service mariadb-service react-service
```

Errors I am seeing:

Maria DB pod:

```
0/2 nodes are available: persistentvolumeclaim "mariadb-pvc" not found. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling.
```

Backend Pod:

```
    Back-off restarting failed container java in pod java-backend-549b6cc7d-xr5rc_eks-sample-app(f1570913-04e4-4c39-8e3b-eab29b274989)
```

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: db: Name or service not known
```

When viewing front end from external-ip from cluster:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
```

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<html> <h"... is not valid JSON
```

The main issues I am seeing:

- my backend pod has a CrashLoopBackOff status
- my mariadb pod has a pending status because of some issue with the PVC
- communication between these services is off somewhere

Could someone provide some insight on what might be happening here? Thank you so much!

Comment: You should probably change the database container to a StatefulSet that can manage its own persistent storage.  When you connect between containers, you need to use the Service name `mariadb-service` as a host name.